# MongoDB with iOS app

Tags: mongodb

My case is: I have an `iOS` application, now I want to use `MongoDB` to store my data.

But when I tried to connect like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;

self.mongo = [MongoConnection connectionForServer:@"127.0.0.1:27017" error:&error];
```

I always receive `mogo object is null`.

Can I do it? If yes, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let me explain:

1. Your IOS app as you describe it is trying to use a connection string that contains the address `127.0.0.1`. This is the localhost adapter, and as yet I have not heard of MongoDB running on IOS.
2. Related to the point above where you are doing the wrong thing, again *you are doing the wrong thing*. You **do not** want to connect your application directly to MongoDB.

For all kinds of reasons, primarily security, you do not want your database openly exposed to the web. This has **always** been and even in 2014, remains a very bad idea.

You need a "webservice" of sorts, to act as a go between for your phone application and your database. You can find [some links](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) in the MongoDB documentation for some possible solutions.

Otherwise Google or build your own. REST API's are not hard. But **do not** connect directly.